# determine total order am i correct

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> T on N×N so that (a,b)T(c,d) iff ab less than cd
>
> let's abstract as (a,b)=x,(c,d)=y, there is xTy or yTx .
>
> ((0,0)=0,(1,1)=1) , ((0,0)=0,(1,2)=2) , ((0,0)=0,(1,3)=3) , ((0,0)=0,(1,4)=4)....so on
>
> ((1,1)=1,(1,2)=2) , ((1,1)=1,(1,3)=3) , ((1,1)=1,(1,4)=4)....so on
>
> ((2,1)=2,(1,3)=3) , ((2,1)=2,(1,4)=4))....so on
>
> am i correct?all are comparable.and it is a total order.

Comment: Usespacesforreadibility.

Comment: thx i corrected it

Answer (score 0):

T is not a linear (total) order because
neither (0,1)T(1,0) nor (1,0)T(0,1).

Comment: sorry,but if (0,1)T(1,0) appear,does it violate anti-symmetric which is property of total order?

Comment: It does not appear.  @toby